# Magento 2: How to remove "Did you mean" section from search page?

Tags: magento2, catalog, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch as search engine, but I want to hide the section where it says **Did you mean** and **Related search terms**:
[image]
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/search-configuration.html#general-search-options

You can disable(select no) following both the options, from *System Configuration ->  Catalog -> search*

**- Enable Search Recommendations**

**- Enable Search Suggestions**

Comment: Awesome, for one reason that was confusing for me. Thank you!